# Applovin banner placement in Android studio

Tags: ads, applovin

Trying to place Applovin banner ads at the bottom of page. But it keeps appearing above page.

''' ViewGroup rootView = findViewByID(android.R.Id.content);

rootView.addview(adview); '''

Comment: If you're implementing banners programmatically in Java, try something like: adView.setLayoutParams( new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( width, height, Gravity.BOTTOM ) );

Comment: Follow this guide https://semicolonspace.com/applovin-max-banner-ads/